# Anyone knows how to code this polynomial into python:?

Tags: python-3.x, polynomial-math

Are there anyone help me how to write this polynomial into python language please, I’ve tried my best, but it’s too hard
P/s sorry for my bad grammar, i’m from vietnam
[image]

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/48228113/10934636

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you simply want to be able to get y result for either one of those equations, you can just do the following:

```
import math
def y1(x):
    return 4*(x*x + 10*x*math.sqrt(x)+3*x+1)

def y2(x):
    return (math.sin(math.pi*x*x)+math.sqrt(x*x+1))/(exp(2*x)+math.cos(math.pi/4*x))
```

If you want to evaluate y1 or y2 given a certain x, just use y1(x), for example:

```
print(y1(10))
print(y2(10))
```

If you want to be able to plot those equations in python, try using the python turtle module to do so.

Comment: Alternatively you could use matplotlib to plot said equations, which in my opinion, is easier than Turtle